# localStorage is working wrong in my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a problem with the localStorage in my application. When I add items to a list of "favorites" they are stored without any problem in the localStorage, they can even be deleted by clicking them again.

But when I refresh the page, my application doesn't read that these items are in the favorites list and therefore doesn't mark them. Also, when I add a new item to the favorites list it causes it to delete everything from localStorage and start over.

Here's a gif of the localStorage view

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../../SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import FiltersBox from '../FiltersBox/FiltersBox.js';
import { getItems } from '../../../Database/Database.js';
import './ItemsContainer.css';

function ItemsContainer() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    const [favoriteItems, setFavoriteItems] = useState([]);
    let localItems = localStorage.getItem('Favorite Items');

    const [sortPrice, setSortPrice] = useState('');
    const [filterCategory, setFilterCategory] = useState('');

    const addItemToFavorites = item => {
        let existentItem = favoriteItems.find(favItem => favItem.id === item.id);

        if (existentItem) {
            let filterTheExistentItem = favoriteItems.filter(
                favItem => item.title !== favItem.title
            );

            setFavoriteItems(filterTheExistentItem);

            let stringItems = JSON.stringify(filterTheExistentItem);
            localStorage.setItem('Favorite Items', stringItems);
        } else {
            setFavoriteItems([...favoriteItems, item]);

            let stringItems = JSON.stringify([...favoriteItems, item]);
            localStorage.setItem('Favorite Items', stringItems);
        }
    };

    const filteredItemsList = () => {
        let newItemList = [];

        newItemList = items.filter(item => {
            if (filterCategory !== '' && filterCategory !== 'none') {
                return item.category === filterCategory;
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        });

        if (sortPrice === 'ascending') {
            return newItemList.sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1));
        } else if (sortPrice === 'descending') {
            return newItemList.sort((a, b) => (b.price > a.price ? 1 : -1));
        } else {
            return newItemList;
        }
    };

    function onSortSelected(sortValue) {
        setSortPrice(sortValue);
    }

    function onCategorySelected(categoryValue) {
        setFilterCategory(categoryValue);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems().then(res => setItems(res));
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        let xd = JSON.parse(localItems);
        console.log(xd);
    }, [localItems]);

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBar setSearch={setSearch} />
            <FiltersBox
                items={items}
                setItems={setItems}
                onSortSelected={onSortSelected}
                onCategorySelected={onCategorySelected}
            />
            <div>
                {filteredItemsList()
                    .filter(item =>
                        search.toLowerCase() === ''
                            ? item
                            : item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search)
                    )
                    .map(item => (
                        <div key={item.id}>
                            <div>{item.title}</div>
                            <button
                                className={favoriteItems.includes(item) ? 'si' : 'no'}
                                onClick={() => addItemToFavorites(item)}>
                                Add to favorites
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ItemsContainer;
```

And here I leave a GIF with a continuous console.log of the localStorage:

[image]

I tried everyrhing, and I don't know what is happening.

Comment: You never read localStorage into `favoriteItems`.

Comment: @gre_gor Thank you for your answer. How do you suggest I can read it?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You cannot add a new problem after you've received an answer. To ask about that new problem, use the Ask Question button above and to the right of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're retrieving your items in `localItems` and... you do nothing with this variable. You should initialize your state `favoritesItems` with your local storage

```
const getItemsFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const items = localStorage.getItem('Favorite Items');
  return items ? JSON.parse(items) : [];
}


const [favoriteItems, setFavoriteItems] = useState(getItemsFromLocalStorage())
```

Comment: Hello! It was helpful, and now when I add or remove items from that favorites list they don't reset my local storage, it works fine now too, thanks so much for that :). But now I have another question... Do you know why the buttons of the items that have been added to the favorites list are not red? I think it's because the conditional is looking in the "favoritesItems" array, but it's empty when I reload... How can I do a conditional for the buttons that are still red using just the locaStorage array? You can see that conditional at the bottom of the code. I'm going to add an answer with GIF.

Comment: You should store only `item.id` in your localStorage. JS can only compare objcet references, not content. So when you initialize your state, the objecs' references in your state and your items have nothing in common. So store only `item.id` and use it in your comparisons (for the classname and for add/delete in your array) and everything should work!

Comment: Thanks again @dbuchet. I tried what you said and now it works. But the little problem now is that there are multiple "items" with the same id inside the array. I tried to solve it on my own but without any success... I'll leave you a GIF in the edition of my question.

Comment: I assume this is because of your `let existentItem = favoriteItems.find(favItem => favItem.id === item.id);` which shiuld be now `let existentItem = favoriteItems.find(favItem => id === item.id);` which could even be now `let existentItem = favoriteItems.includes(item.id)`

Comment: Yeah, literally a minute before you posted that answer I just changed `let existentItem = favoriteItems.find(favItem => favItem.id === item.id);` for `let existentItem = favoriteItems.find(favItem => id === item.id);`, and now I changed it for a `let existentItem = favoriteItems.includes(item.id)` as you said and all works fine now. Thank you so much @dbuchet, seriously... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, you can flag the answer as correct if you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is where the culprit is:

```
    const [favoriteItems, setFavoriteItems] = useState([]);
    let localItems = localStorage.getItem('Favorite Items');
```

You load `localStorage` into `localItems`, but you expect it to be in `favoriteItems`,  where you have never assigned it. You would need to specify the item of `localStorage` as the initial state, like:

```
    let localItems = localStorage.getItem('Favorite Items');
    const [favoriteItems, setFavoriteItems] = useState(localItems ? localItems : []);
```